# skip rotate of custom shareExtesion

Tags: ios, swift

i have a shareExtension with custom viewController:

```
class ShareViewController: UITableViewController{

}
```

if i rotate phone it has been rotated, i would like to fix it to portrait orientation and i have used this code:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```

[image]

But it does not work, any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project's general tab, look up 'deployment info', select your options for 'device orientation'

[image]

Comment: i don't have device orientation in the deployment info

Comment: I am sure you do have it, I added a picture in my original answer to show you where it is.

Comment: i have option in my app, not in my share extension, i have attached screen in the original answer

Comment: Ah, missed that you were working on share extension. I think you're only option is to override shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations as you did. I just tested it in swift3 and this works well for me.

Comment: hmm, I skipped the whole swift2.2 ... so guessing here a bit; if you do not implement shouldAutoRotate() iOS will do the rotation for you and should show your app in .Portrait always. If you implement shouldAutoRotate() returning false, you will need to do the rotation yourself - override didRotate()